# Porting Wolfram Alpha curve to Java

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to replicate the Mew-like Curve as a particle effect. I've tested the Particle playing with other X and Y formulas so thats fine, but I can't seem to work out this one.

Formula: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKZQN.jpg

Where: θ = Heaviside step function

sgn = signum

I think I've ported the main code right, I'm just having trouble working out what t is, I assume its the theta so theta as radian, however the code doesn't seem to provide the same result.
I think the heaviside function might be wrong but I can't seem to find anymore information the formula and what is should be.

Heres a pastebin of which I currently have.

pastebin.com/iU0jEaLU

Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an image (or other graphic) of your desired output?

Comment: Could you link us to the Wolfram Alpha page directly and/or give us the raw "Mathematica" source code to see exactly what they mean by the theta function?

Comment: Hey guys. Its supposed to look like this www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Mew-like+curve the original .nb Mathmetica file is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2vz5t8c4ioh3w5/WolframAlpha--Mew_like_curve__Equations_.nb?dl=0. If you need this in another format let me know :D

Comment: There is also some more reading on the creation process of other curves here: http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/